# KML opens with the wrong geoposition

Tags: kml, polyline, geo

I'm trying to create a map of the Stockholm's subway lines in Fusional Tables.
 In the Fusion Tables I created a map with geo each station:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1K7F2DMY5JBA6ZQOH8a1a4dQjwxoksRDMJ3-wPEg#map:id=3

I want to connect them to the polyline.
 Options to create polylines and way in the tables there, or they are very well hidden.
 So I created this KML file and loaded into tables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
   <Document>
    <name>Stockholms T-bana</name>
    <description>Karta &#246;ver r&#246;da linjen i Stockholms T-bana</description>
    <Style id="redLine">
      <LineStyle>
        <color>FF0000</color>
        <width>2</width>
      </LineStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
      <name>R&#246;da linje</name>
      <description>T-bana linje</description>
      <styleUrl>#redLine</styleUrl>
      <LineString>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
        <coordinates>59.330947,18.059263,2357
          59.335258,18.074055,2357
          59.343169,18.081243,2357
          59.345826,18.071712,2357
          59.365568,18.054891,2357
          59.381508,18.036516,2357
          59.392019,18.041697,2357
          59.398709,18.03622,2357
          59.338683,18.091242,2357
          59.347202,18.098793,2357
          59.357298,18.102218,2357
          59.32316,18.06762,2357
          59.319309,18.072295,2357
          59.316958,18.063308,2357
          59.317778,18.050152,2357
          59.316057,18.033714,2357</coordinates>
      </LineString>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Maps created in the table stubbornly opened in the Arabian Sea but not in Stockholm.
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1trp44L7vNDqPVDmTr1yXmGUpBvS7_U6R0MnBsS4#map:id=3 
What is my fault? Is there some other way create polylines in tables between objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the coordinates backwards.  [KML coordinates are longitude,latitude,altitude.](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#coordinates)

Sweden:
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=59,18&hl=en&sll=18,59&sspn=61.939621,78.046875&t=m&z=16

Arabian Sea:
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=18,59&hl=en&sll=18,59&sspn=61.939621,78.046875&t=m&z=16

[Your KML with the coordinates corrected](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_PolylineReversed.kml)

Comment: Yes, it all works. A thousand thanks. It is not clear why the entire region KML did the opposite.

Comment: Where did your original KML come from? If this answered your question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)