# kmllayer with polygons hide map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

Based on [Google Map's KML Layers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml) I have a kmllayer to load polygons from
http://www.vis-it.com.ar/www/barrios08062015081002PM.kml

The map loads ok, but when load the klmlayer the map is hidden, all map_canvas are shown in blue and the polygons are rotated from its original position. Each same coord shows OK one polygon at the time, but the kml behaves that way.
My kml is formatted from kmlreference documentation, and I tried with `<Altitude>` tags but the result is the same.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue (in the question itself)?  Where did the KML come from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [KML opens with the wrong geoposition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410830/kml-opens-with-the-wrong-geoposition)

Answer (score 0):

You have your coordinates backwards in the KML.

[KML coordinates are longitude,latitude[,altitude].](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#coordinates)

[your kml on a map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/barrios08062015081002PM.kml)

snippet from it:

```
<Placemark>
<name>64 VIVIENDAS</name>
<visibility>0</visibility>
<Polygon>
<extrude>1</extrude>
<innerBoundaryIs>
<LinearRing>
<coordinates>
-29.766407681574762,-62.047154903411865,0
-29.76759976891944,-62.04902172088623,0
-29.769052606190985,-62.047669887542725,0
-29.766407681574762,-62.047154903411865,0
</coordinates>
</LinearRing>
</innerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>
</Placemark>
```

[fixed (reversed coordinates)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/barrios08062015081002PM_revCoords.kml)

snippet from it:

```
<Placemark>
<name>64 VIVIENDAS</name>
<visibility>0</visibility>
<Polygon>
<extrude>1</extrude>
<innerBoundaryIs>
<LinearRing>
<coordinates>
-62.047154903411865,-29.766407681574762,0
-62.04902172088623,-29.76759976891944,0
-62.047669887542725,-29.769052606190985,0
-62.047154903411865,-29.766407681574762,0
</coordinates>
</LinearRing>
</innerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>
</Placemark>
```