# KML layer not showing up on Google Maps

Tags: maps, kml

It's been a while since I've worked with KML so I may be missing something obvious, I know it has something to do with my coordinates

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <name>A Rectangle</name>
    <Polygon>
      <extrude>1</extrude>
      <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
            51.078523,-114.134937,50
            51.078523,-114.133737,50
            51.077323,-114.133737,50
            51.077323,-114.133937,50
          </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
    </Polygon>
  </Placemark>
</kml>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KML opens with the wrong geoposition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410830/kml-opens-with-the-wrong-geoposition)

Comment: Your coordinates are backwards: http://www.feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fkml%2FSO_20161025_coords.kml (should be -114.xxx,51.xxx,50)

Comment: Thanks! That was it.